# Convergence of $\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n+n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

$a_{n}= \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n+n}$

$b_{n}=\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+3} \cdots + \frac{1}{n+n}$

I can show that $b_{n}$ is increasing and bounded and therefore convergent and that $a_{n}$ is $\frac{1}{n} + b_{n}$, which, as the sum of two convergent sequences, should converge, however!! I should be able to "expand" the limit to each sequence term and calculate them individually, which seems to give me a sum of $0$'s as n goes to infinity, which goes against what I understand an increasing sequence to be. Hopefully, someone can enlighten me here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: FYI "I should be able to "expand" the limit out to each term of the sequence" is a common misconception. For example, consider $a_i = 1/i + 1/i + \ldots + 1/i$ (i times). Then "term wise" each term goes to 0, but $a_i = 1$ always.

Comment: Another way to do compute $\lim_n a_n$ is "Riemann sum".  But, of course, the question does not ask how to evaluate the limit.  It asks what is wrong with this term-by-term argument that the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

As $b_{n}=\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+3} \cdots + \frac{1}{2n} = \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} \cdots + \frac{1}{2n} - (\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} \cdots + \frac{1}{n})$
$= \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} \cdots + \frac{1}{2n} - 2(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{6} \cdots + \frac{1}{2n}) = \frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} \cdots + (-1)^{2n+1}\frac{1}{2n} = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$, and $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} b_{n} = ln(2)$

So, the way of this term by the term is just confusing. Because when you want to calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_{n}$ which is equal to $(\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+3} \cdots + \infty)$, you can't go term by term, as it is not a finite sum anymore.